# Code sync not happening on google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

We are using google compute engine and have some instances and groups setup. We have connected our code to the bitbucket repository. All our setup works fine. However periodically (and this is happening now), the code that is pushed to bitbucket is not reflected in our instances. Once this happens this lingers for quite a while (as in the code will stay frozen as of a specific date and no new merges will refresh).

We've tried reaching out to google support without much success. Anybody face a similar issue? Any thoughts on what we can do to 
a. resolve this and
b. prevent this from happening in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean "connected our code to the bitbucket repository"? Do you use a cron job that does "git pull"?

Comment: So we are using a startup script on the compute engine group. That startup script connects to the repository and does a git pull. So everytime we reset the instance, we expect to get the latest code. This was not happening. The way we resolved it currently is to disconnect the git repository in the google cloud console and recreated it to point to bitbucket.  Still wondering why this happens in the first place and if there is a better solution.